# Issue with xslt processing

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I get the following error after my xslt has been processed:

> There are 1 schema validation error(s):
>   1. Error Msg:The element 'BusinessObjectList' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'BusinessObject'. Line Number: 1, Line Position: 40, Severity:Error

I am trying to troubleshoot this issue and just require some clarifications. From my understanding of this error, there is a missing element called BusinessObject. So, I am not too sure if i have to incorporate this missing element or replace the existing element with this? another question too is, how to refer to Line 1, Line Position 40 in my xslt file?

Below is how the beginning of the xslt looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <BusinessObjectList SchemaVersion="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="HierarchicalObjects-1.0.xsd">
```

Comment: The XSLT code you have inserted in your question has `version="2.0"`, yet you have used the [tag:xslt-1.0], why is that? As for the validation error, which tool gives that? And does that really occur after the XSLT has been processed (executed?), I guess it is just an error message your editor gives trying to validate parts of your XSLT as the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` links to a schema.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us how you are running the transformation, but it seems to be configured so that on completion the result document is validated against the schema at HierarchicalObjects-1.0.xsd. Presumably that schema says that the BusinessObjectList must contain at least N BusinessObject elements (perhaps N is 1, we don't know), and your transformation output includes less than N.

You either need to produce output that conforms to the schema, or you need to change the way you are processing to avoid the validation step.

The line/column number probably refers to a line/column in the result document, not in the stylesheet.